# full text searching on particular site archived via archive.org

Tags: archive.org

Is it possible to do full text search of a given site which is archived by archive.org?

For example,

###### Search:

```
Keywords: ванна OR ванну
Site:     realty.tut.by
```

###### Result:

```
https://web.archive.org/web/20210513190614/https://realty.tut.by/news/building/661351.html
```

Answer (score 3):

It is not possible to do full text search on Internet Archive Wayback Machine. But according to [this page](https://help.archive.org/help/using-the-wayback-machine/) it might be implemented in the future:

> **Can I search the Archive?**
>
> Using the Internet Archive Wayback Machine, it is possible to search
> for the names of sites contained in the Archive (URLs) and to specify
> date ranges for your search. **We hope to implement a full text search
> engine at some point in the future**.

Answer (score -1):

If I understand correctly you'd like to find specific words, or sentence's on a page?
If so, press "f3" on windows, or "Ctrl+F" if on Mac to pull up the "find bar" to search any word or sentence.